# Are QR Codes Really More Easily Read by Computers

Tags: qr-code

[This](http://www.howtogeek.com/162394/qr-codes-explained-why-you-see-those-square-barcodes-everywhere/) article claims that

> QR codes are machine-readable labels — computers can understand them much more easily than they can understand text. QR codes are used for everything from tracking products to identifying items — typical tasks where they function as improved UPC barcodes

Is that a true statement that QR codes are more easily read then text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, proof UPS,FEX ED, and etc all use them.

QRcode are simple pattern of binary values either a 1(black) or 0(white) and that is it.  QRCodes were designed to be read by machine.  The squares can be bigger or smaller, but you still have a 2 digit alphabet.  There are no different fonts,styles, or anything.  Also because they are so uniform sizes can be auto-detected. They also built-in error checking which is never done,sure spell check can help on text but sometimes it also causes errors, with individual letters when typing or handwriting.  If the checksum doesn't balance you read the code wrong, try again.  Most QRcode also have alignment squares to make sure the computer rotates them into near perfect alignment before reading them.

Typed text has these complexities that QRcodes don't.

- 96+ foreign letter symbols. (Unicode!)
- many different size
- 1000's of fonts, lets can be vastly different in each font.
- different colors
- types like bold,italic,underline
- dirt,smudge, etc can make one letter look like another.
- text has no alignment symbols, it could, but no one does it.
- Pages with specs, and signs of age wear and tear take extra steps to filter.

Handwriting adds even more complexities:

Each one of our handwriting is so unique specialist exist for banks that use that to determine forged checks and alter documents to reasonable certainty.

All of the complexities mean it is way slower, and less accurate.  For example, I have Omnipage Pro, and it does an excellent job recognizing text, but it takes at least 10-60 seconds a page depending on a list of issues.  Many things it can't auto correct for 3D perspective correctness, which is a simpler computation for qrcodes.  If you don't scan at ideally 600dpi or more, and the accuracy goes way down.  Angle it wrong, and it may not be able to fix it, but QRcodes have alignment corners.  The program is literally running a list of pre-processors,processors, and post-processors to make the recognition possible.  It has to process 600*8.5 (page width)* 600*11 (page height) pixels which comes out to 33.6 million or more pixels at higher dpi.  All of this just to correct for the variation I listed above.

In many business, like FEDEX time in small increments is big money.  They literally read millions of barcodes a day, and even if it was only 1 second longer to translate 1 second times a million barcodes is a lot of time wasted.

Comment: WIth enough time, I can read a QR code, but there are some peoples handwriting I could never read.

Comment: -1  Your answer is all over the place. The first sentence is irrelevant. The second sentence is true of text too , so irrelevant. Your third sentence doesn't consider the obvious possibility of  text with the same font(it's not like if it's not QR codes then the font must be variable).  What about text with a particular font? And who says that text can't have error checking.  It seems almost every sentence you wrote is deeply flawed and not thought out.  It may be true that QR codes are better but you have not produced a clear argument as to why.

Comment: @Keltari  Exactly, and the reason why you can read a qrcode, and not some handwriting is because they use simple 2 digit alphabet of 1 or 0 and that is it.  There no possible way to shape the parts of a barcode differently, the standard committee designated squares and that is it.

Comment: @barlop is there was an easier way surely the big companies would have bought into that technology.

Comment: Actually you missed a key point: i.e. like UPC it's designed to be machine readable.  The complications faced by OCR are well documented.

Comment: @sawdust  I guess that I assumed that was inferred as computers operate in binary 0's and 1's and so does QRcodes.

Comment: @cybernard You haven't understood me